# Only Keep last 4 or 5 images on ECR

Tags: amazon-ecr

Hello guys as we all know that there's a limit on storing images on ECR and that's why we want to keep only last 4 or 5 images on ECR.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ECR Lifecycle Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html) to delete all but the last 4 images with the following policy:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rulePriority": 1,
            "description": "Rule 1",
            "selection": {
                "tagStatus": "any",
                "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
                "countNumber": 4
            },
            "action": {
                "type": "expire"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```